# Create and display clickable cell of cells in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, uitableview, matlab-guide, cell-array, clickable

I want to display a cell matrix in Matlab GUI. Moreover, some of that cells are arrays of cells, and I want them to be clickable and that by clicking on them I activate a function.

Imagine I have a cell matrix:

```
A=cell(2,2); 
A{1,1}='Column1';
A{1,2}='Column2';
A{2,1}={'A','B','C','D'};
A{2,2}={'E','F'};
```

I want to display it on an GUI, and I want to be able to click the cells, say to see the content of A{2,1}. Then I would like to click the cell entries in this cell array, and by doing so, I calculate a new matrix of the same form to display on the GUI.
However, uitable doesn't allow me to use a cell array.

An alternative would be to have a matrix of the form:

```
A=cell(5,2);
A{:,1}={'Column1','A',B',C',D'};
A{:,2}={'Numbers',1,2,3,4};
```

And by clicking the numbers (which I can do) a buttongroup would display (of undefined size), and by selecting one it would calculate a new matrix of the same form to display.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you can't

MATLAB GUI only provides only a very parse set of possible gui-elements [check this documentation of MATLAB GUI](http://de.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-gui.html). You need to change your request, so e.g. create an [uitable](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitable.htm) or something [like this](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/interactive-list-box-in-a-guide-gui.html). If you desire to create more advanced stuff in MATLAB GUI's, then you should start to look into this fellas [documentation](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/)